# Flutter Scoped Model - Passing multiple Models

Tags: flutter, scoped-model

I've been playing with Scoped Model recently and was wondering if there's a better way to push multiple models onto the tree for use by children.

Suppose I have a 'AppModel' that's a composition of all the Models I need

```
class AppModel extends Model
{
  ModelA a = new ModelA();
  ModelB b = new ModelB();
  ModelC c = new ModelC();
}
```

I start by adding this model to the tree from `main`

```
runApp(ScopedModel<AppModel>(
    model: AppModel(),
    child: MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      home: Home(),
    )),);
```

This causes the application to start at a Home page with an AppModel available in the tree

The Home page is a series of buttons each leading to another page which may use several of the models from AppModel

When a button is pressed I want to open the relevant page and pass the 'sub-models' that are needed from AppModel

Currently I have the `onPressed` for my buttons looking something like this, where I nest Scoped Models

```
() => Navigator.push(context, 
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScopedModel<ModelA>
          model: ScopedModel.of<AppModel>(context).a,
          child: ScopedModel<ModelB>(
             model: ScopedModel.of<AppModel>(context).b,
             child: PageAB())))))),
```

Within `PageAB` I can these access the relevant model via `ScopedModel.of()`

```
ScopedModel.of<ModelA>(context).modelAGet
ScopedModel.of<ModelA>(context).modelAFunc()

ScopedModel.of<ModelB>(context).modelBGet
ScopedModel.of<ModelB>(context).modelBFunc()
```

Is this the correct way to share (multiple) models? Or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I have already answered this question on this link, it can also help those who still consider combining multiple models in a single model. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56692571/3589715

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is one way you can do it. I use Mixins to compile different beahviours / features into the AppModel. Each model is responsible for a section/feature in the application. As an example I have a UserModel, SettingsModel and ContentModel

They are all mixins on the Model class from the ScopedModel library

```
mixin UserModel on Model {
 ...
}
mixin SettingsModel on Model {
 ...
}
mixin ContentModel on Model {
 ...
}
```

And then my main AppModel looks like this

```
class AppModel extends Model with UserModel, SettingsModel, ContentModel {
  ...
}
```

This way I'm combining behaviours from different models, if you want to only expose the one type of model you can cast it and use that interface.

I'm curently leaning towards this way where the Model files manages all the state for certain features and in those models I inject services which are singleton instance to share information between them if needed. These services perform all my actual business logic, Connecting to the API, serializing and compiling into contextual information for my app.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like an interesting alternative - I'll have to do some brushing up on mixins!

Comment: @user6635665 you're welcome :) here's a link to the article that helped me understand the reason for it's existence and how to use it. https://medium.com/flutter-community/dart-what-are-mixins-3a72344011f3

Comment: @FilledStack I'm struggling with similar problem - could you share with me your PageAB's code so I can take a look how you retrieve ScopedModel in there? Do you pass ScopedModel in PageAB's constructor ?

Comment: @Matt I did a full video here on ScopedModel. In short I use get_it to inject the model where it's needed. https://youtu.be/JsjDLHxGz4M

Comment: will check it out today, tkank you! :)